# Persistent cookie gets deleted when IE is closed. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET app which uses forms authentication with an option to persist cookie in the login screen. I am testing in local computer which means no web farms are used. 
In Chrome and Firefox when I log in and persist cookie, then close the browser and then bring up the same page, I am already logged in. So far so good.

In IE however, when I load the same page after closing IE, I get the login screen instead of automatically being logged in. I checked the authentication cookie and noticed that the cookie is gone when I am in the login screen the second time. I see the cookie after logging in and I see it expires a month in the future. My guess the cookie gets deleted when IE closes. I don't know why this happens.
I have repeated this test several times. I see the authentication cookie after logging in but it's gone in the login screen.

"Empty temporary Internet Files Folder when browser is closed" is NOT checked in Tools->Advanced

I am using IE9 in IE8 standards mode in Windows 7 64bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't mention the fact the site uses https. In the test server where this issue occurred, I use a self-signed ssl certificate. When I installed my root authority cert, the problem seems to have gone. This issue happened in IE only.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/11/troubleshooting-stored-login-problems-in-ie.aspx) from [Erik Law](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/ericlaw%20%5Bmsft%5D/) about this. Check it for more details. Scroll down to section `Troubleshooting Login Cookies`. If you have specific question about anything, edit your question and let us know.